# How to convert gray scale png image to RGB from comand line using image magick

Tags: imagemagick, png, rgb, grayscale

I am trying to convert an png Gray scale image to RGB png image using the following command.

```bash
convert HopeLoveJoy.png -size 1x1 -fill "rgba(0%,1%,2%,0)" -draw "color 511,511 point" out_test.png
```

By using the above the above command I am able to convert but the color of the image is getting changed.
Is any thing wrong in the command??
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mmmm... what exactly are you trying to achieve? At the moment, you open a file, set the size of any new images you later create to 1x1 although you don't then create any, then you set the fill colour using `rgba()` and draw a point at 511,511.

Comment: I just want to convert the Gray scale png image to rgb png image.

Comment: @mounikam You can try this command `convert gray.png -type truecolormatte PNG32:color.png`, which convert a gray png named `gray.png` to be a true color png named `color.png`.

Answer (score 11):

If, as your question title implies, you really just want to go from greyscale to sRGB colorspace, use this:

```
convert image.png -define png:color-type=2 result.png
```

I check it like this:

```
convert image.png -define png:color-type=2 result.png && identify -format "%[colorspace]" result.png
sRGB
```

Comment: Still the result image is being in gray scale format.. I checked it using the command 
" identify -format %[colorspace] result.png "

Comment: If the image contains only gray pixels "identify" will tell you it's grayscale.  If you need to know the actual PNG storage format, use "identify -verbose" and look for "IHDR" in the output.