# Convert JPG image from grayscale to RGB using imagemagick

Tags: command-line, imagemagick, jpeg, rgb, grayscale

I am trying to convert gray scale images to RGB using the [imagemagick command-line tools](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php).

It is working fine for PNG images, using:

```
convert image.png -define png:color-type=2 result.png
```

(taken from an answer to ["How to convert gray scale png image to RGB from comand line using image magick"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34305379/how-to-convert-gray-scale-png-image-to-rgb-from-comand-line-using-image-magick))

Although checking with `identify -format %r result.png` will still return *DirectClass Gray*, I can see it worked using `gdalinfo` as there are now *3* bands / channels listed:

**gdalinfo [successfully converted PNG]:**

```
Driver: PNG/Portable Network Graphics
Files: result.png
Size is 567, 479
Coordinate System is `'
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  479.0)
Upper Right (  567.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  567.0,  479.0)
Center      (  283.5,  239.5)
Band 1 Block=567x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=567x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=567x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

However, it seems the [`-define` option](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#define) is only working for PNG images.

**My question:** How can I achieve the same effect for JPG images?

When I try the above command for JPG, it does not work:

```
convert image.jpg -define jpg:color-type=2 result.jpg
```

**gdalinfo [unsuccessfully converted JPG]:**

```
Driver: JPEG/JPEG JFIF
Files: result.jpg
Size is 1500, 1061
Coordinate System is `'
Metadata:
  EXIF_ColorSpace=1
  EXIF_PixelYDimension=2480
  ...
  EXIF_YCbCrPositioning=1
  EXIF_YResolution=(300)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0, 1061.0)
Upper Right ( 1500.0,    0.0)
Lower Right ( 1500.0, 1061.0)
Center      (  750.0,  530.5)
Band 1 Block=1500x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  Overviews: 750x531, 375x266, 188x133
  Image Structure Metadata:
    COMPRESSION=JPEG
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The PNG colour types do not apply to JPEG images, so you can't use the same technique. Try forcing the colorspace to sRGB, and/or setting the type to TrueColour so you don't get a palettised image:

```
convert input.jpg -colorspace sRGB -type truecolor result.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response.
For the record:  `convert input.jpg -type truecolor result.jpg` worked fine. While adding `-colorspace sRGB` yielded the same result, using it by itself did not get the job done.

Comment: Doesn't work for a PNG file, I tried:`-colorspace sRGB -type truecoloralpha` my image is 8 bits and I don't want to convert it to PNG24.

Comment: @Shayan If you have a question, please ask it in the usual way by posting a question along with your image.

Comment: @Shayan According to [this post on the ImageMagick forum](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=33180), you also have to use `-define colorspace:auto-grayscale=off`. I would imagine that the detection for grayscale is applied at the time you save and whatever conversion you had before that won't force the colorspace one way or the other.

Comment: With PNG, you have to specify the prefix PNG24:filename.png to convert from grayscale 8-bit to color 24-bit.

Answer (score 1):

image-magick *refuses* to process png, but `ffmpeg` does not.

> ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i ${file} *-sws_flags
> "lanczos+accurate_rnd+full_chroma_int+full_chroma_inp+bitexact"* -y
> **-pix_fmt rgb8** test.png

reported depth *of end file is* 8 bit.
(also useful for rgba → rgb.)