# How to convert in-place batch of PNG from grayscale to RGB?

Tags: imagemagick, mogrify

So, I want to convert many PNGs from grayscale to RGB, similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34874771/convert-jpg-image-from-grayscale-to-rgb-using-imagemagick)

However, the given command there does not work for PNGs. Moreover, that is `convert` and I read that to process images *in-place* one would have to use `mogrify`. How can I use this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is both [a bug](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=24814) and [a feature](http://adamish.com/blog/archives/746) of imagemagic. To quote the *feature* part:

> It turns out ImageMagick tries to set to PNG8 **based on image content** even if the file was previously PNG24 or PNG32

Therefore, if you want to end up with 3 channels per image, you have to set `png24` format (`3` channels `x` `8` bits/channel).

So the solution is:

```
# for a single image, with a different output
convert input.png -type TrueColor png24:output.png

# for a batch of images, IN_PLACE !!! BE VERY CAREFUL 
mogrify -define png:format=png24 -type TrueColor *.png
```

It's mandatory to realise that `mogrify` will modify them **in place** so make sure this is what you want, as there is no way to recover the original images.

Comment: Since PNG only supports sRGB (no CMYK), adding -colorspace RGB is going to make the image linear color rather than non-linear color sRGB. So unless you are using a very old IM version where RGB and sRGB are swapped, I would remove that. Also proper IM syntax reads a raster input before supplying any settings or operators. So in the convert command read your input png first.

Comment: @fmw42 thank you for advice! Any idea why `mogrify` is so slow ? Takes ~32 seconds for 18 images. If I look in the folder, I see intermediate files being created in the process. Maybe it uses a small memory buffer and if the images are big it uses the disk, despite having memory available

Comment: Note that it is possible to avoid files being modified in-place by setting `-path /some/where/else`.

Comment: Try running `identify -list resource` to see if you have limited memory, for example, available.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have enough free memory on my machine, but maybe IM uses small buffers for the transformations, similar to how `sort` becomes very slow with large files, but can be speedup with `-S` flag

Comment: Just because you have free memory on your machine does not mean ImageMagick can/will use it. You need to run the command I suggested to see if there are restrictions on ImageMagick.